# 'DrawObject' was not declared in this scope error using std::vector, trying to store class object (c++)

Tags: c++, object, scope, instance

Trying to have my "layer" class, put 3 objects "drawObject", into it's vector, and getting out of scope error.

Everywhere I see they just do "vector >Class< vectorName"; and it works!

layer class:

```
#include <vector>
#include "DrawObject.h"

using namespace std;

class layer
{
    public:

        layer();
        virtual ~layer();

    private:

        vector<DrawObject> objects; <--------------- Error here! "'DrawObject' was not declared in this scope"
};
```

DrawObject class:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "AnimationSet.h"

class drawObject
{
    public:

        drawObject(char* name, char* surfaceFile, int xPos, int yPos, int drawLevel, bool willMoveVar, int animationNumber);
        drawObject(char* name, char* surfaceFile, int xPos, int yPos, int drawLevel, bool willMoveVar);
        virtual ~drawObject();
        SDL_Surface* loadImage(char* surfaceFile);
        SDL_Surface* getSurface();
        void setSurface(SDL_Surface* surface);
        char* getName();
        void setName(char* name);
        int getID();
        void setID(int ID);
        float getX();
        void addX(float xAdd);
        void setX(float xSet);
        float getY();
        void addY(float yAdd);
        void setY(float ySet);
        bool isSprite();
        void setIsSprite(bool isSprite);
        bool willMove();
        void setWillMove(bool willMove);
        bool draw();
        void setDraw(bool draw);

    private:

        SDL_Surface* surface = NULL; // Imagem, no caso de único sprite; caso contrário, spritesheet.
        char* name;
        int ID;
        float xPos;
        float yPos;
        bool isSpriteVar; // Se isSprite, imagem é spritesheet.
        bool willMoveVar;
        bool drawVar;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<DrawObject>` should be `vector<drawObject>`, no? C++ is case-sensitive, you defined the class `drawObject` but attempt to use `DrawObject`.

Comment: @user1896797 why are you including `AnimationSet.h`? Don't. Include it in the cpp file if you need it.

Comment: I took out the drawObject declaration, it was in there by mistake (was trying things to solve error, pasted code with that in)

Overlooked that, corrected, thanks. (the include)

Comment: @user1896797 What do you mean you took out the declaration?

Comment: Where now I have this:

"vector<DrawObject> objects;"

Before I had this:

"DrawObject drawObject;

vector<DrawObject> objects;"

Comment: @user1896797 changes nothing.

Comment: @user1896797 Did you change `vector<DrawObject>` to `vector<drawObject>` (note the 'D' to 'd') as Luchian suggests?

Comment: EDIT: It works. I have no idea why when he first suggested it, I tried and it did not work. What's the explanation for this working? Ain't I supposed to give the vector argument the TYPE of the storage? Wouldn't it be DrawObject? Why drawObject?

Comment: @user1896797 You have `class drawObject{...}`.  The name of the file does not matter, its the actual class definition and when you define the class you used `class drawObject`.

Comment: Oh dammit, when I changed all of the file names and class declarations to CamelCase, I missed that one! No wonder it did not work... godammit, thanks alot!
And an apology for making you both grind you teeth at my stupidity...